# How do I fetch a particular item from html code using bs4?

Tags: python, html, json, regex, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML code. I want to convert the HTML code below:

```
<div class="company_data__list">

 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Name</div><div class="company_data__data">ABC Company<br/>Subtitle</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Capital</div><div class="company_data__data">230000</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Total</div><div class="company_data__data">103</div></div>

 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Name</div><div class="company_data__data">XYZ Company<br/>Subtitle</div> 
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Total</div><div class="company_data__data">10</div></div>

 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Name</div><div class="company_data__data">CAT Company<br/>Subtitle</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Capital</div><div class="company_data__data">430000</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Total</div><div class="company_data__data">10233</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">URL</div><div class="company_data__data">www.abc.com</div></div>

</div>
```

into a Json file which looks like this:

```
{ id: '1',
  data:{
    name: 'ABC CAT Company',
    capital: '230000',
    total:'103'
  },
  id:'2',
  data: {
    name: 'XYZ CAT Company',
    total:'10'
  },
  id:'3',
  data: {
    name: 'CAT Company',
    capital: '430000',
    total:'10',
    url:'www.abc.com'
  },


}
```

I'm using python3, bs4, re (Regular Expression)

Comment: If you're using bs4, why would you need regex to retrieve that data ?

Comment: I realised that! Edited my question. thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far, what doesn't work ? If you just need a function, you can try `soup.find()` or `soup.find_all()`, to which you can give "div", and even some filtering like `attrs={"class": "company_data__data"}`. This might be helpful : https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I will read a bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="company_data__list">

 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Name</div><div class="company_data__data">ABC Company<br/>Subtitle</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Capital</div><div class="company_data__data">230000</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Total</div><div class="company_data__data">103</div></div>

 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Name</div><div class="company_data__data">XYZ Company<br/>Subtitle</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Capital</div><div class="company_data__data">330000</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Total</div><div class="company_data__data">10</div></div>

 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Name</div><div class="company_data__data">CAT Company<br/>Subtitle</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Capital</div><div class="company_data__data">430000</div></div>
 <div class="company_data__row"><div class="company_data__head">Total</div><div class="company_data__data">10233</div></div>

</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
content = soup.find("div", class_="company_data__list").find_all("div", class_='company_data__data') #Find required DIV
with open(filename, "w") as csv_file:       #Open File
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)           #Create CSV object
    for i in range(0, len(content), 3):
        temp = [j.text for j in content[i:i+3]]
        writer.writerow(temp)               #Write Content
```